# How do I handle %20 into spaces for a django filter for queries?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

```
class SomeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = SomeModel
    fields = {
        'column1': '__all__',
        'column2': '__all__'
    }
```

So basically lets say I have a GET request using this filter like www.someAPI.com/?column2=something%20or%20Another

When I apply the filter above, it doesn't work because it's querying column 2 with %20 instead of spaces (which is what is in the sql database) how can I handle this so it queries correctly?

Comment: extremely unlikely. Django always url decodes querystrings. You have a problem with some other part of your code

Answer (score -1):

You can use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

```
import urllib

old_string = 'stringwith%20'
new_string = urllib.unquote(old_string)
```